# Add new lookup column - customer return within 30 days

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, datediff

**Context of the problem**: When a customer purchased items at a grocery store on a given day, it is recorded as a row in the transaction table, I want to add a "lookup" column in the select statement to check if same customer have another transaction within 30 days.  The "30 days" is current transaction date + 30, the new lookup column will add to the end of select *.

**db.transaction**:`Customer_ID, Transaction_ID, Transaction Date`

**Query returns**: `Customer_ID, Transaction_ID, Transaction Date,  **Return within 30 days (Yes/No)**`

I thought the new lookup column could be a **case** expression but I don't know how to get the **next available** transaction date for the same customer and comparing with the transaction date in the current row.

```
case 
   when datediff(day, transaction_date,  "next available date")<=30 then 'Yes
   else 'No'
end as 'return_within_30_days'
```

Thanks for any help!  (I am using SQL Server)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEAD` to get a customer's next transaction. Your "next available date" translates to

```
LEAD (transaction_date)
  OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY transaction_date)
```

The complete query:

```
select
  customer_id,
  transaction_id,
  transaction_date,
  case 
   when datediff(day, 
                 transaction_date,
                 lead (transaction_date)
                   over (partition by customer_id order by transaction_date)
                ) <= 30
   then 'YES'
   else 'NO'
  end as return_within_30_days
from mytable
order by customer_id, transaction_date;
```